# Sum up previous values of a column

Tags: python, addition, dataframe

I am dealing with a rather simple problem, but cannot find a solution.

Let's consider the following table:

> A
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 2

I would like to create a new column (B) the sum of Row A until the respective index:

> A
> B
>
> 1
> 1
>
> 4
> 5
>
> 5
> 10
>
> 2
> 12

I was thinking and searching for a solution but could not find one. You have an idea how to proceed?

My approach:

1. create default column with 0. df['B']=0
2. df['B']=df.B.shift()+df.A

Is there a way to solve the problem in Python?

Comment: Have you tried your approach? What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
lA = [1,4,5,2]

lB = [sum(l[0:i+1]) for i in range(len(l))]
```

And if you don't get list comprehension here is a more verbose version of the code:

```
lB = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    lStuffAbove = l[0:i+1]
    lB.append(sum(lStuffAbove))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t = [1,4,5,2]

f2 = 0
for f1 in t:
    f2 += f1
    print f1, f2
```